# How to redirect all sub-directory pages to parent directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect:

**URL1:**

```
http://www.example.com/folder/whatever-pagefolders-anything/
```

To:

**URL2:**

```
http://www.example.com/folder/
```

So typically no matter how many folders come after the "folder" it will redirect to example dot com/folder/

Some other examples to make it more clear

**Example 2:**

**URL1:**

```
example.com/folder/folder2/folder3/
```

To:

**URL2:**

```
example.com/folder/
```

**Example 3:**

**URL1:**

```
example.com/folder/page.html
```

To:

**URL2:**

```
example.com/folder/
```

**Example 4:**

**URL1:**

```
example.com/folder/*
```

To:

**URL2:**

```
example.comcom/folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/$ http://example.com/folder
```

What this basically does in corresponding to your question is redirect anything (be it sub directories, or files) inside the folder directory to your parent folder.

Comment: Does .htaccess file need to be place on my "example.com/folder" directory (where every sub-directory under that folder needs to be redirect there ) or on my root folder?

Comment: On "example.com/folder". If that doesn't work, you can always copy the code on both the .htaccess in the root folder and in "example.com/folder"